# How to find the element in the list of checkboxes that has only 'data-identifier' diffrent in selenium webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium

No other field is different like id,name,class etc.Xpath is not working .
I am trying to write in c sharp

driver.FindElement(By.Id("field_Select")).click(); is not working. THis is same for all the checkboxes.Please help.

Comment: Could you post some HTML?  It will be very difficult to create a selector/xpath if we don't have that.

Comment: <input id="field_Select" class="ace-checkbox-2 ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" type="checkbox" data-identifier="109914" data-ng-change="field.Change" data-ng-model-fn="'data.' + field.Key" data-ng-name-fn="'field_' + field.Key" name="field_Select" ng-model="data.Select"> . Only the  data-identifier field is diffrent for diffrent checklist

Comment: Is `data-identifier` the same each time the page displays?

Comment: Are you looking for the one checkbox that has a different value for `data-identifier` out of a set of checkboxes?

Comment: It is not changing each time the page displays.

Comment: Yes. I want to select the first checkbox . All have diffrent data-identifier #.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to click the first check box, I think this will work for you:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.Id("field_Select"));
elements[0].Click();
```

Another approach that might work, assuming `data-identifier` is always the same:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[data-identifier='109914']")).Click();
```